# react-native: how to stick tab bar to top when scrolling?

Tags: react-native, react-native-tab-view

I am using `react-native-tab-view` for handling tabular navigation. Is it possible to, when scrolling down, have the tab bar scroll with, but stick to the top of the screen once it reaches the top? So something like ScrollView's `stickyHeaderIndices`.

Here's an example of what I want, where the tab bar "Posts, Comments, About" sticks to the top.

[image: reddit example]

Comment: Have you achieved this Michael?

Comment: Have you?? @Marwin

Comment: @Sjonchhe Haven't done it

Answer (score 7):

It's manageable to build with react-native-tab-view, but not so trivial. This week I published a package to specifically solve this issue, it is super simple to use [here](https://github.com/PedroBern/react-native-collapsible-tab-view#quick-start) is the quick start example, and below is the demo.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> One of the possible solutions is this.

1. Calculate the scroll position from the top of the tab component using `onScroll` callback method os `ScrollView`.
2. When the contentoffset.y is zero, so just make the component `absolute` and make its `top: 0`